# How to send post request of Messaging API

Tags: c#, json, post, messaging

**What I want to do**

I want to send "post request" following the link below. More specifically, when you open the link, you can see "Example request" which goes like this.

```
'{
    "messages":[
        {
            "type":"text",
            "text":"Hello, world1"
        },
        {
            "type":"text",
            "text":"Hello, world2"
        }
    ]
}'
```

In sample it sends two messages but, I just want to send one.

I don't know how to write in C#

Send broadcast message

This is the code where I'm struggling.

```
        // To creat HttpClient
        var client = new HttpClient();

        // Accesstoken
        var accessToken = "my token";

        // URL
        var url = "https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/broadcast";



        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        // Request Header
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "type", "text" },
            { "text", "Hello World" }
        };

        var parameters2 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
        {
            { "messages", parameters}
        };

        var str = @"{""messages"":""  {""type"": ""text"",""text"" : ""Hello World""}""}";



        var content = new JObject(str);


        request.Content = new StringContent(
            content.ToString(),
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json"
        );

        await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Of course it doesn't work

**question⓵**

How can I write the example In C#???

**question⓶**

If you can, could you provide entire procedure of Send broadcast message from scratch?

**PS**

For those who are worried, I'm still gathering answers in my first question and also trying to make it work.

Comment: I fogot putting the link. https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/#send-broadcast-message

Comment: This is not a question. This is business requirement. You should research, try to do something then if you have any particular code problem, you can ask. But where is the code? I don't see any.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

The procedure is below.

1. To make a class following this link http://json2csharp.com/
2. To serialize that

3.
To useu ToString() to a serialized json

And the entire code is like this

```
            // To creat HttpClient
            var client = new HttpClient();

            // Accesstoken
            var accessToken = "my token";

            // URL
            var url = "https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/broadcast";

            // Post
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);


            // Request Header
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

            // To create messages
            var message1 = new Message("text", "Hello World1");
            var message2 = new Message("text", "Hello World2");
            var root = new RootObject();
            root.addMessage(message1);
            root.addMessage(message2);

            // To serialize
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);

            request.Content = new StringContent(
                json.ToString(),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json"
            );

            await client.SendAsync(request);
```